# Setting the unique ID for row in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to set a unique ID for each item that is added to my database similar to Drupal nodes. Just not sure how I know what the next number would be when adding a new item to my database. 
MySQL statment is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `HERDSIRES`(uid, name, color, gender) VALUES ( VALUE of next uid, '$name', '$color',  '$gender')";
```

I am thinking I need to query the database prior to the INSERT and find out what the value of the last uid and then add 1 to it and then save it into a variable.  I am just not sure if this is the best way.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the column is set to autogenerate by the database, you can just pass `null` in the `INSERT` statement and MySQL will do the rest.

For example, on a primary key column with `auto_increment` specified.

Yours would be:

```
INSERT INTO `HERDSIRES`(uid, name, color, gender) 
VALUES ( null, '$name', '$color',  '$gender')";
```

Or you could omit it entirely since you are enumerating the fields anyway:

```
INSERT INTO `HERDSIRES`(name, color, gender) 
VALUES ( '$name', '$color',  '$gender')";
```

edit: Here's how to use PHP to get the last autogenerated ID from a table:

```
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO ...');
$new_row_id = mysql_insert_id();

// do something with $new_row_id
```

Comment: Sorry I left this out. I am adding different pieces of the same item to different tables this. i am going to use this UID when call all the pieces of data from different tables.

Comment: In that case you want to use `mysql_insert_id()` after inserting the first row, and then using that value in your next query or queries. That PHP function is a proxy of the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` that is mentioned in another answer. I updated the above answer to include that.

Comment: Be wary of AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL when using InnoDB. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't use `autoincrement`?  SQL will take care of that for you automatically.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is horrible in MySQL if you are using InnoDB. It does not retain the last record value between server restarts. Thus, if you start with 500 records, delete 100 random records, and restart MySQL, MySQL recalculates the next record number by counting the current number of records + 1. In other words AUTO_INCREMENT is a bad idea in MySQL if you do not take steps to preserve the AUTO_INCREMENT variable and restore it upon reboot (for any table using AUTO_INCREMENT).

Answer (score 1):

set the field in the table to auto increment, then do not set the field when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

[How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

> For [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), the most
>   recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis.
>   It is not changed by another client.
>   It is not even changed if you update
>   another [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column with a
>   nonmagic value (that is, a value that
>   is not NULL and not 0). Using
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT
>   columns simultaneously from multiple
>   clients is perfectly valid. Each
>   client will receive the last inserted
>   ID for the last statement that client
>   executed.

Comment: Can I use LAST_INSERT_ID()  if I am INSERTING data of the item into different tables. (sorry i left that out) So one table will have just the name, date added and the UID the other table will have the UID and the rest of the info.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() works with AUTO_INCREMENT columns. LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT or UPDATE statement to affect such a column.